How can I override a file that is missing from a website in chrome dev tools?
I work for a company, and the service we use for e-commerce has asked me to give them a css file with updates for the template they have created for clients.
In the  section of the website, there is a  to a css file called "brand.css" that will have my updates to apply on top of their defaults. However, until I send one for them ti drop in, there isn't a file here.
I understand through chrome dev tools that I can apply overrides to css files and it makes a copy on my computer that will load instead of the live version (usually for testing purposed), but since the "brand.css" is missing, I am not finding a way to have the browser load my local copy even from the local folder that was created for overrides.
The REAL goal here is to crate a setup where I can make changes in CSS through the dev tools "styles" pannel that stay persistently across page reloads.
My alternative for now is to override the main CSS, then do a diff/compare when I am finished to create a file of only overrides for the web guys, but that seems fraught with user error to comb through all that manually...
Does anyone know how to link to a file when one doesn't exist to create the override link for?

I tried making other overrides and putting a new file by the same name in the same directory, I have tried a pending a new CSS file to the head section before and after page load, but I get mixed media messages about security or keep facing problems "loading local files," but ultimately I want this to be persistent between page loads.
I have contact the developers and ask them to put an empty CSS file where this one is supposed to be, but until I hear back, I will keep exploring.

Sounds like a missing feature that you can suggest to devtools developers.
